# Android TV Box Gigabits Connection

Tags: networking

Is there any android apk app which is able to display a LAN network connection speed such as 100Mbps or 1Gbps.

If this is not possible, is there any app that is able to display the network chipset info in Android TV box?

Comment: Without telling us which model of Android TV you've bought, it's impossible to answer this question.

Comment: It has nothing to do with model. The model may indicate that it ships with gigabits connection but I want to know whether is it malfunction.
I am asking is there any android app to show the connection speed or showing the network chipsets

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just connect the ethernet cable directly to a switch or a PC that is able to display the link speed.